# issue in update controller

Tags: laravel-5

1. > i got the issue while updateing
   >              NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:    in RouteCollection.php line 161    at
   >       RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 821    at
   >       Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691    at
   >       Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
   >       at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246    at
   >       Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request))    at
   >       call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
   >       line 52    at
   >       Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in
   >       CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44    at
   >       CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
   >       at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode),
   >       'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php 
   >       line 136    at
   >       Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))    at
   >       call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
   >       line 32    at
   >       Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))    at
   >       call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php
   >       line 103    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line
   >       132    at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in
   >       Kernel.php line 99    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in
   >       index.php line 54

**For the given issue Here is my Controller**

```
public function update(Request $request ,$id){

        print_r($request);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**View**

```
{!! Form::model($website, ['method' => 'PATCH   ', 'route' => ['websites.update', $website->id]]) !!}`
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('user', 'User Name:', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
{{ Form::text('user', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
{!! Form::submit('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Here My route**

```
  Route::post('websites/{id}/update',
    ['as' => 'websites.update', 'uses' => 'WebsiteController@update']
);
```

Comment: you can send id from hidden field

Comment: still not working... will u please elaborate it so i can understand it

Comment: You are using method patch but route is post, they should be the same. Either patch or post, but the same.

Comment: use route like website-update

Answer (score 1):

Thanks For every one to helping me out. But i Uses this and now it is work fine. Thanks again!!

```
 {!! Form::model($website, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['websites.update', $website->id]]) !!}`
        .
        .
        .


        Route::any('websites/{id}/update',
            ['as' => 'websites.update', 'uses' => 'WebsiteController@update']
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method differs and should be the same as route
Let's change like this:

```
{!! Form::model($website, ['method' => 'PUT', 'route' => ['websites.update', $website->id]]) !!}`
.
.
.


Route::PUT('websites/{id}/update',
    ['as' => 'websites.update', 'uses' => 'WebsiteController@update']
);
```